# Datagridview SQL returning no results

Tags: sql, datetime, datagridview, where-clause, vb.net-2010

Upon loading the form, this code is carried out:

```
Try
            MyConn2.Open()
            da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_bookings WHERE DateOfBooking = " & DateTime.Today, MyConn2)
            ds2 = New DataSet
            da2.Fill(ds2)
            DataGridView3.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)
            MyConn2.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If MyConn2.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConn2.Close()
        End Try
```

This is supposed to retrieve all results where the date of the booking column is the same as the date today (the current date).

As it stands the datagridview throws up no errors but loads only the field names into the datagridview, not entries that meet the specification (entries with the current date).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of vb.net, but from the SQL side this could be caused because you are trying to compare a date value (e.g., 4/20/2015) with a date time value (e.g., 4/20/2015 at 11:57 AM). This kind of comparison will look at the time portion of the first date as midnight (4/20/2015 at 12:00 AM), and thus return no matches.

If any of the values in your table have times, or if your vb function returns a time other than midnight, try replacing your SQL with something like the following:

```
"Select * 
from tbl_bookings 
WHERE CAST(DateOfBooking AS DATE) = CAST('" & DateTime.Today & "' AS DATE)", MyConn2
```

Comment: when using this, i get an error regarding the  MyConn2 & " AS DATE)" part  stating the operator '&' is not defined for types 'system.data.oledb.oledbconnection' and 'string'

Comment: hmm, no error now but nothing is loaded into the datagridview upon running

Comment: Next steps, then ... Have you tried running the SQL against the server and verifying the results returned (`Select * from tbl_bookings WHERE CAST(DateOfBooking AS DATE) = '4/20/2015'`)?  Have you printed out the contents of the `DateTime.Today` function and verified it is what you expect?  Are you sure your connection string is accurate?

Comment: Try taking the WHERE clause off of your SQL statement and seeing if values return (you can use `SELECT TOP 100 *` if you are concerned about too many rows).

Comment: I removed the WHERE clause and the entire table loaded in. I also checked that datatime.today is the correct value, which it is

Comment: OK ... I made a tweak to add quotes around the date, check that. Also, did you check the SQL directly to ensure that records exist for today?

Comment: I think the issue is the records in the database contain both the date and time, perhaps I should edit the datetimepicker so it only provides the date when writing into the database? How would I Do That?

Comment: Using `CAST(DateOfBooking AS DATE)` should take care of removing the time portion, so I wouldn't worry about that ...

Comment: hmm well then i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

I think you need single quotes around the date

```
da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_bookings WHERE DateOfBooking = "' & DateTime.Today & "'", MyConn2)
```

Comment: when using this I get an error which states Value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'system.data.oledb.oledbcommand'

Comment: You should convert the date to calendar date fomat using DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")